# Unable to connect to my home Wi-Fi in Windows 8.1 but can connect to other Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, windows-8.1

This seems to be a classic issue for many, and therefore I have tried all the classic solutions already, let me explain in detail:

I am using an old Lenovo laptop. It was running on Windows 10 and recently, I downgraded it to Windows 8.1, since then I am only able to connect to the mobile networks but I am not able to connect to my home Wi-Fi.

Note: Other devices, such as few mobile phones and a laptop running on Ubuntu, are connecting to my home Wi-Fi without any issue.

Solutions that I have tried :

1. I used some driver pack solutions to get updated drivers & also tried few Wi-Fi drivers from Lenovo site.
2. I tried some `netsh` commands like `/release`, `/renew`, `/flushdns`
3. Also tried tweaking with power options (which may affect Wi-Fi performance on low battery)
4. Followed some YouTube videos and tried changing IPv4 and IPv6 subnets back and forth.

None of the other solution worked for me!

Please let me know if someone have sorted this out.

Comment: Why did you downgrade it to 8.1 if 10 was working?

Comment: The laptop was running on Windows 8.1 earlier. Installing Windows 10 was an experiment, but it affected the performance a lot and made the system slower. Therefore, I decided to switch back @NetServOps

Comment: So to clarify, you had 8.1 installed, you upgraded to 10 (not a fresh install), then you downgraded from 10 back to 8.1? 
I would suggest you do a clean install of 8.1.

Comment: I did fresh installs every time with ISOs.. didnt upgraded or downgraded @NetServOps

Comment: Try it with a wired connection first - let it get all its updates, including the driver updates - this could take about a day with all the auto restarts.  Once it has finished all its updates, unplug the wired connection and see whether the wireless magically starts working.  It may be, that in the case of Linux, you are trying the latest versions but in the case of windows, you are trying a 7 year old version.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have never faced such problems on my HP Touchsmart 15 Notebook running Win8.1

A simple solution I can recommend to you is forgetting all known networks, and connecting to your home network after that.

Also, the problem might even be with your home Wi-Fi. If it connects well enough with other devices, then that's fine.

Rather than the problem residing in your OS, there may be hardware issues or configuration errors in your PC's Wi-Fi module.

That's probably till the best of my knowledge.
Hope you get your problem solved

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, actually I tried to forget the networks.
I am able to connect my home Wi-Fi in many other devices. I have really tried many similar solutions that I could find online. But, still no luck.